# Update throws error message Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run this query:

```
update [test].[test_data] 
set [test].[test_data].[Attribute] = (select [Attribute Name] 
                                      from [AF].[Producer Well Template] 
                                      where [test].[test_data].[Attribute_old] = [Existing Attribute Name])
```

It throws this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the  subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

`[AF].[Producer Well Template]` table has fewer records than `[test_data]`

Thanks,
S

Answer (score 1):

This means that your inner query below is returning more than one value for Existing Attribute Name. Your inner query should only return one value for each field that [test_data] row that needs updating. This makes sense since you can only update the attribute to one value and if there are more than one return from the subquery it has no idea which of the multiple values to use.

```
select   [Attribute Name] from [AF].[Producer Well Template] where
[test].[test_data].[Attribute_old]=[Existing Attribute Name]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Update [test].[test_data] 
   set [Attribute] = pwt.[Attribute Name] 
from [test].[test_data] td 
  inner join [AF].[Producer Well Template] pwt 
    on td.[Attribute_old]=pwt.[Existing Attribute Name];
```

But still you have to find the SQL to make it a single item.

Comment: yea, that's the problem, how to get this single item

Comment: @JoeGreen,  how could I know that? You have the data, you didn't give any schema and sample data.

Comment: sorry, I found out the issue, now make sense. Thanks @Cetin Basoz

Answer (score 0):

I would write the query like this (so it is more readable):

```
update td
    set [Attribute] = (select pwt.[Attribute Name] 
                       from [AF].[Producer Well Template] pwt
                       where td.[Attribute_old] = pwt.[Existing Attribute Name]
                      )
    from [test].[test_data] td;
```

The problem is pretty obvious -- there are multiple matches in the subquery.  You can readily find the culprits by doing:

```
select pwt.[Attribute Name] 
from [AF].[Producer Well Template] pwt
group by pwt.[Existing Attribute Name]
having count(*) > 1;
```

If you just want to get rid of the error, then use `select top (1)` in the subquery.